# iPhone Development Related Podcasts?

Tags: iphone, podcast

Anyone have any suggestions for good iPhone development related podcasts?

Only one I've run across is http://www.mobileorchard.com/ and was looking for some others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Pragmatic Programmer](http://www.pragprog.com) has some video casts, but they are $5 each. There is a two-part series on [using Xcode](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-mcxcode/becoming-productive-in-xcode), and five-part series on [writing your first iPhone application](http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdiphone/writing-your-first-iphone-application).

Comment: Anyone comment on the quality and usefulness of these videos?

Comment: @schooner: Sorry, I should have been more clear that I hadn't actually watched them. I just wanted to point them out because I stumbled across a blog that spoke highly of them. I think there might be free previews of some of them so you can get a taste without laying down any cash.

Comment: Thanks.  I had a look at the samples and they seem decent, only issue is the iPhone one is 7-8 months old now, so I wonder how much it has changed with the SDK updates.  I'd also be interested in hearing what people usingthem thought first hand in terms of it they helped them learn.

Comment: @schooner: You could read the discussion forums for the videos. Here is the one for Writing Your first iPhone Application:  http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/84

Answer (score 3):

Just came across a reference to a new podcast, [Build and Analyse](http://itunes.apple.com/podcast/build-and-analyze/id404064215).

Comment: I'm enjoying it. Not technical, but good developer discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Late Night Cocoa and other shows on the [Mac Developer Network](http://www.mac-developer-network.com/) feature iPhone topics every now and then.

[CocoaCast](http://cocoacast.com/) also has iPhone episodes, which tend to be a bit more practical.

Comment: The MDN Show has become iDeveloper Live. http://ideveloper.tv

Answer (score 0):

NSBrief is new and is a bit more technical, though not overly so.

http://NSBrief.com

Answer (score 0):

I realize this thread might be a little old and has a marked answer. However it was one of the top results when I googled "iphone podcast" which is the reason for my reply.

Stanford has a class on Iphone Development and you can view it by subscribing to it on Itunes. I've been watching these classes and they are good to get started on Iphone Dev

More info about this can be found on [podcastingnews.com](http://www.podcastingnews.com/content/2009/04/stanford-podcast-teaches-iphone-app-development/) or at the [Stanford on the itunes website](http://itunes.stanford.edu/)